# Django Forms - getting data from multiple choice fields

Tags: django, forms, get

I have a form like so:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    site = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SITE_CHOICES, label=ugettext_lazy('Site'),)  
    ...
    params = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
             choices=PARAM_CHOICES,
             label=ugettext_lazy('Select Parameters'),
             widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
             )
```

And in my template:

```
<form action="{% url results %}" method="get">{% csrf_token %}
{% for field in myform %}
<div class="field_wrapper">
    {{ field.errors }}
    {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="{% trans 'Query' %}"  />
</form>
```

My problem is that when I submit the form as GET the variables are like the following:

```
    site=1&params=foo&params=bar&params=something&submit=Query
```

my `params` variable is clearly being overwritten by the last choice? How can get access to the submitted data as separate variables?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you actually tested it, or are you just making assumptions off the URL? For a `MultipleChoiceField` the result should be a list of the submitted values in `request.GET['params']`. Is it a list or is it literally just the last `param`?

Comment: OK - My bad. The variables are actually passed as a list into GET. I did check it but my method was faulty.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Using Django forms

You **should** be using Django's form handling with a `POST` which would majke things easier. Here goes:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = MyFormClass()
else:
    form = MyFormClass(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        do_something_with(form.cleaned_data['params'])
        return redirect('somewhere')
return render_to_response('my_template.html', RequestContext(request, {'form':form}))
```

#### Notes on using `GET` vs `POST` with forms

It's useless to include `{% csrf_token %}` if you're going to `GET` the form (Absolutely no csrf validation is done with `GET` requests, which make sense, as `GET` requests are supposed to be non-data-altering.

Anyway, if you're really going to `GET` the page, you can still use the same logic as written before, with a little tuning:

```
form = MyFormClass(request.GET)
if form.is_valid():
    do_something_with(form.cleaned_data['params'])
    return render_to_response('some_template.html', {'stuff':some_stuff})
return render_to_response('form_submission_page.html', {'form':form})
```

Last thing, using `GET` to submit data is usually bad practice, unless you're creating some search function or altering display (pagination & all).

### Using `request.GET`

Now, if for some reason you **don't want to use Django forms**, you can still get around the problem and retrieve your `params`, you simply need to use the `QueryDict.getlist` instead of using the `QueryDict.get` method.

Here goes:

```
my_data = request.GET.getlist('params')
```

### Documentation

Don't forget to check out the Django documentation on [`QueryDicts`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) and on [`forms`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. One point that isn't so clear to me is the use of `GET` vs `POST`. I have always been under the impression that submitted data which does not alter the database should be `GET` (as in getting data) and `POST` is used to update/alter databases. In this case I have a form for searching only, which led me to conclude that I should use `GET`.

Comment: If you're indeed submitting a search form, `GET` is the appropriate method to use. In included a snippet on how to use forms with a `GET`-only page.

Answer (score 2):

And use `{% csrf_token %}` in get request is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Use `form.is_valid()` and `form.cleaned_data['params']`.